# How to refresh root node in jstree?

Tags: jquery, jstree

I'm partially refreshing my jstree using `refresh_node(id)`. This works fine for all loaded nodes except for the root node with special id `"#"`. The issue is that jstree does not even attempt to query my json source. I can reload the root node by calling `load_node("#")` without any isses. I'd like to use `refresh_node("#")` though so I don't lose the tree state. Does anyone know why this is not working?

Just found a workaround: Calling `refresh()` will produce the result that I would expect `refresh_node("#")` to produce. It's rather odd that not all nodes can be treated equally.

Comment: If that fixes your issue and is what you desired you can answer your own question and mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: Cool! That's good to know. In this case though, it's just a workaround, not the proper solution to the issue.